# The getter 'product' isn't defined for the type 'Object - flutter -Modalroute.settings.arguments error

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

```
class DetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static String routeName = "/details";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Object? arguments =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments != null;
    var product;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF5F6F9),
      appBar:AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        leading: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0,),
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              color: Colors.white,
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              ),
          ),
        ),
        leadingWidth: 70.0,
        ),
      **body: Body(product: arguments.product),**
      );
  }
}



class ProductDetailsArguments {
  late final Product product;

  ProductDetailsArguments({required this.product});


}
```

I cant get the product details in the flutter android app and this shows a error in

**body: Body(product: arguments.product),**

Anyone please help I am stuck in this for a week now. Can't really get a solution ..

i have tried the **body: Body(product: arguments?.product),** and everything thats in the internet. I am new to flutter and this is far above my knowledge so I dont understand how it works correctly. The far I understand is that it is used to get the product name from the list from the item we touced in that product page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```dart
final ProductDetailsArguments? arguments =
        ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as ProductDetailsArguments?;
```

And use the way you did

```dart
Body(product: arguments.product)
```

But if your `Body` `product` doesn't accept nullable data, do a null check and then pass the product

```dart
body: arguments?.product!=null ? Body(product: arguments.product) : Text("got null")
```